# 401 errors exclusively on iPhone on login with nuxt auth and django rest framework simple-jwt

Tags: iphone, django-rest-framework, nuxt.js, http-status-code-401

So this is a strange one that I've been struggling with. At this point just looking for ideas because I'm all out..

Back-end auth system is django-rest-framework simple-jwt which is deployed on Heroku.
Front-end using nuxt auth deployed on a VPS.
No authentication issues on Windows, Android mobile or mac...
iPhone returns a 401 error every time.

nuxt.config.js

```
  auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: {
        scheme: 'refresh',
        token: {
          property: 'access',
          maxAge: 1800,   // seconds
          type: 'Bearer',
        },
        refreshToken: {
          property: 'refresh',
          data: 'refresh',
          maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30
        },
        user: {
          property: false,
          // autoFetch: true
        },
        endpoints: {
          login: { url: 'auth/token/', method: 'post' },
          refresh: { url: 'auth/token/refresh/', method: 'post' },
          user: { url: 'api/v1/me', method: 'get' },
          logout: { url: 'auth/logout/', method: 'post' }
        },
      },

    },

Even tried overriding jwt.TokenObtainPairView adding permissions.AllowAny and still no go:
class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
   
    authentication_classes = []
   
    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        token = super().get_token(user)

        # Add custom claims
        token['fname'] = user.fname
        token['lname'] = user.lname
        token['email'] = user.email
        token['category'] = user.category
        # ...

        return token

class MyTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer
```

Eternal gratitude if anyone can offer ideas to solve this...

Comment: Not sure if it's feasible with an iPhone, but maybe try to plug it somehow to a browser, it's probably help you debug what is happening or at least, provide some error code: https://medium.com/@nikoloza/how-to-debug-remote-ios-device-using-chrome-devtools-f44d697003a7